# Oracle ADF PartialTrigger on OutputText with multiple buttons reference

Tags: oracle, button, triggers, oracle-adf

I have a OutputText that has a binding to a Bean and that runs a certain function that updates the text of the OutputText, also this OutputText has a partialTrigger to a Button, which makes the function to run when the button is pressed.

What I want is that this binding on the OutputText to be activated not only when one button is pressed but when Button1 or Button2 is pressed.

```
 <af:outputText id="ot19" value="No Entity Selected" binding="#{newBean.presentOutputText}" partialTriggers="b1"/>
```

On the partialTriggers="b1", I would like to have something as partialTriggers="b1 or b2"

How can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do this

```
<af:outputText id="ot19" value="No Entity Selected" binding="#{newBean.presentOutputText}" partialTriggers="b1 b2"/>
```

In the past, I've had trouble with outputText's not responding to partialTriggers.  In that case, you might want to use `<inputText readOnly=true />`

Comment: Thank you :) this is exactly what I wanted :) It is so simple but for someone who is starting is was being difficult to find a solution. Thank you